# How to add source line breaks in CKEditor 4.4

Tags: ckeditor

I'm running CKEditor 4.4.7 and, by default, the HTML source has no line breaks, nor tabs.

I've tried to configure the source formatting per [HTML Output Formatting](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format), but this documentation appears to be out-of-date.  A console log of `editor.dataProcessor.writer` shows that it has no `lineBreaksChars` attribute (and adding one does nothing), nor a `.setRules` method.

Is there a way to get line breaks in the HTML output in version 4.4.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the [htmlwriter plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/htmlwriter). You can either [download](http://ckeditor.com/download) a different build of CKEditor or download the plugin and add it manually with [`config.extraPlugins = 'htmlwriter'`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins).

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/eyxL3h2b/).